# Deploy .NET Framework 4.6.1 in IIS

Tags: .net, iis

I try to deploy my website in a IIS server, Is a old website doing in .NET Framework 4.6.1, I publish in the server, I don't see any error only see the main directory of the website

```
 4/14/2021  2:49 PM        <dir> bin
 4/14/2021  3:07 PM        <dir> Content
 1/11/2021  2:10 PM          351 ExcludedFiles.wpp.targets
 1/11/2021  2:10 PM           99 Global.asax
 4/14/2021  3:09 PM        <dir> Views
 4/14/2021  4:22 PM         7109 Web.config
```

Something like that!

What I have to do to see the main page of my website?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Default Document component in IISmanager, and then add the full name of the page you want to visit.

Here is the steps:

1.Find the Defualt Document and double click it
[image]

2.Enter the page you want to display

[image]